# PreUpdate in Hibernate-Envers

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

To activate post-update listner for envers there is a class `EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl` to extend. It works well. There is also post-collection listners. But there is no pre-update listner. How can i intercept pre-update events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to intercept pre-update events, simply use the mechanism from Hibernate directly and extend the `PreUpdateEventListener`. Envers implements *some* of the listers to provide auditing functionality.